# Compile native Windows executable from perl source on linux

Tags: perl, compilation

I have a perl script on a linux system that I would like to compile to generate an executable that runs natively on Windows. I would like to do this with free software, preferably Perl PAR / `pp`. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you even tried with PAR?

Comment: Hi Xavier. I tried PAR (pp), but the executable only works on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `pp` on a windows machine to make a windows binary. I know it works, I've done it. Any Linux specific code will need to be made at least platform-independent or windows specific, but Perl is a generally platform independent language. Using [`File::Spec`](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aSpec) will help.

Comment: Thanks @JoelBerger. I downloaded ActiveState perl on windows and downloaded the PAR module, but don't have the pp utility.

Comment: Try installing [`PAR::Packer`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR::Packer) too. Personally I would try the Strawberry Perl distribution rather than AS. AS uses PPM which is less like Linux-based module installation. Strawberry Perl uses a system which contains a Unix-like build system, therefore much closer to a Linux-esque system.

Comment: Also you might cheat and install PAR with PPM, but use `cpan PAR::Packer` at the command prompt to install `pp`. I believe that it is pure Perl so that should work. IIRC this is what I did to make it work

Comment: @Joel Berger, AS provides the same build env as Strawberry in addition to `ppm`. AS released it's 5.14 build mere days after 5.14 came out (if not the day of), and Strawberry still doesn't have a 5.14 build after 7 months (although it appears they have a beta build of it finally).

Comment: @Joel Berger, Many people using the distro's installer to install Perl packages, so claiming `ppm` is unlike linux is a crock.

Comment: @ikegami, I will defer to you, I have booted windows once in the last year. I should have mentioned I looked up [`PAR`](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/PAR/) and [`PAR::Packer`](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/PAR-Packer/) on the AS PPM site. PAR passes and PP seems to have issues, so I was trying to get out in front of it.

Comment: Also I try not to use distro installer for Perl modules anymore, kinda weirds me out.

Comment: @Joel Berger, I try not to use distro *perl*. (perlbrew ftw) If I use the distro *perl*, I use the distro installer.